# How to compose custom command-line argument from file lines?

Tags: bash, command-line

I know about the `xargs` utility, which allows me to convert lines into multiple arguments, like this:

```
echo -e "a\nb\nc\n" | xargs
```

Results in:

```
a b c
```

But I want to get:

```
a:b:c
```

The character `:` is used for an example. I want to be able to insert any separator between lines to get a single argument. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a file with multiple lines than you want to change to a single argument changing the NEWLINES by a single character, the `paste` command is what you need:

```
$ echo -en "a\nb\nc\n" | paste -s -d ":"
a:b:c
```

Then, your command becomes:

```
your_command "$(paste -s -d ":" your_file)"
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to insert more than a single character as a separator, you could use `sed` before `paste`:

```
your_command "$(sed -e '2,$s/^/<you_separator>/' your_file | paste -s -d "")"
```

Or use a single more complicated `sed`:

```
your_command "$(sed -n -e '1h;2,$H;${x;s/\n/<you_separator>/gp}' your_file)"
```

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave is not working for me. You would need:

```
echo -e "a\nb\nc\n" | xargs
```

to get `a b c`.

Coming back to your need, you could do this:

```
echo "a b c" | awk 'OFS=":" {print $1, $2, $3}'
```

it will change the separator from space to `:` or whatever you want it to be.

You can also use `sed`:

```
echo "a b c" | sed -e 's/ /:/g
```

that will output `a:b:c`.

After all these data processing, you can use `xargs` to perform the command you want to. Just `| xargs` and do whatever you want.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the lines using `xargs` and then replace the space(`' '` ) using  `sed`.

`echo -e "a\nb\nc"|xargs| sed -e 's/ /:/g'`

will result in

`a:b:c`

obviously you can use this output as argument for other command using another `xargs`.

`echo -e "a\nb\nc"|xargs| sed -e 's/ /:/g'|xargs`